# Return a list of cliques larger than n with NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, clique

I have a network with more than 90000 nodes. I want to check it for cliques (=sets of nodes in which each node is connected to all other nodes of the set) that have 5 or more members. Is there a command in the NetworkX library that returns all such cliques for my network?

I tried

```
cliques = list(networkx.enumerate_all_cliques(G))
```

but due to the size of the network, the runtime is unacceptable which is why I want to set a threshold of 5 or more members, which will hopefully reduce runtime since less cliques will be considered.

Comment: If I not mistaken you'll still need to compute all the cliques, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But even if there is no way around the computation time, how can I access only cliques with more than 5 members?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create a random graph.
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(100, .2, seed=0)

# iterate over cliques and keep only those with len(clique) >= 5
cliques = [clique for clique in nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G) if len(clique) >= 5]
```

According to the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques.html), `enumerate_al_cliques` returns an iterator:

> Returns **iterator**
>
> An iterator over cliques, each of which is a list of
> nodes in G. The cliques are ordered according to size.

So with the above solution you only keep in memory those with 5 or more members.